# Where's the recommended place to put small python convenience modules

Tags: python, pythonpath

I've amassed a small collection of small handy ad hoc scripts that I would like to have available to me in all my python projects and ipython interactive sessions. I would like to add to and clean up this collection without having to worry about making setup.py files and installing them formally. From the list of directories on the sys.path by default, what's the proper home for these scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user site directory should be the right directory for such things.

```
python -m site --user-site
```

shows you the correct path for your platform. Usually its something like 
 `$HOME/.local/lib/python<version>/site-packages`

You can even put a module `sitecustomize.py` there which will be imported automatically on each interperter startup.